# SharpMap's backgroundLayer on an intranet(no internet) (Windows)

Tags: wpf, sharpmap, mapcontrol

I'm making windows C#(WPF) mapControl on intranet(no internet). (Windows Server)

I get OSM.pbf and mbtiles file.

Is this possible? Please, Look at this picture.

[image]

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TileAsyncLayer osmLayer = new TileAsyncLayer(KnownTileSources.Create(KnownTileSource.OpenStreetMap),
        "TileLayer - OSM");
    this.mapBox1.Map.BackgroundLayer.Clear();
    this.mapBox1.Map.BackgroundLayer.Add(osmLayer);
    this.mapBox1.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use The **Docker** or WSL2 in the Windows server.

Answer:
overv/openstreetmap-tile-server

https://hub.docker.com/r/overv/openstreetmap-tile-server

Detail:

https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts/